# In application how to get differentiate address book contacts in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, contacts, addressbook

I am working on iPhone application in which i am fetching address book contacts. I want to differentiate contacts which are from exchange account & gmail account which are configured on my iPhone. I also want to differentiate particular exchange or gmail account name if two exchange or gmail account are configured in my iPhone.

So how can i achieve this & is there any way to differentiate contacts ?

Please let me know some solution or some sample code to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried this

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef sources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);

But in this array, i m getting all group name but i am not able to identify that particular group belong for what i.e gmail or exchange or if two exchange account is configured in my iPhone then particular group belongs to which account.